# Custom Event Listener for Multi threaded environment in Java Using Wait() and notify()

Tags: java, multithreading, asterisk, wait, notify

I have a multithreaded environment and I want to handle all threads using the event listener.

I have made the listener which will listen to the events, My question is that  i want to wait and notify each thread using some specific unique id or whatever we can use for uniqueness purpose.

I am new in event listener programming in java.

I am making IVR application with Java and on each call my new thread will be created.

Any demo will be highly useful for me.

Comment: Cant you just create a class extended the thread class and add an static attribute to it and increase that in each instance you create from your class. as the attribute is static, for one JVM instance, you will have unique ids for your threads. is that what you need?

Comment: My main task is to notify the thread from the different class. My wait and notify both are in different classes.
Can you show me this with a small example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This wont directly fit to your code, you have to work to fit to you.

This is my idea.

```
public class MyThread extends Thread{
private static int uniqueId;
private int myId;
MyThread(){
    myId = ++uniqueId;
}
//getters and setters to myId
```

}

public class YourClass{

public HashMap threads = new HashMap();// use this to map your threads by ids

```
//when you want to access a thread, you get it from the map and call wait and notify. 
//this map should be publicly visible to you.
```

}

Comment: Quite helpful..!!

Comment: What we will store in hashmap?
uniqueId of MyThread or threadID created by Java?